# Unable to login to Nimbus using Storm Deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, apache-storm

We are following Storm-Deploy ( https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-deploy ) to deploy storm cluster on AWS Cloud. Our cluster is being successfully deployed and the separate EC2 instances are being spawned for Nimbus, Zookeeper and Supervisors.

However we are not being able to connect to Storm UI. Further we are not able to deploy the topology in the cluster as it cannot connect to Nimbus using ssh. 
Each time storm-deploy launches a new cluster, it creates a new key-pair. We are not able to locate where the pem file of the new key pair is being saved.

We have tried connecting with

1) authorized_keys
2) id_rsa
3) id_rsa.pub

As pem file using ssh command with Nimbus, Zookeeper and Supervisors machines.

Each time we are getting the same error:
"Permission denied (public key)"

Please suggest how to login to Nimbus and submit topology./.ssh/

Our pallet.clj file:

(defpallet
  :services
  {
   :default {
             :blobstore-provider "aws-s3"
             :provider "aws-ec2"

```
         :environment {:user {:username "storm"          
                              :private-key-path "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
                              :public-key-path "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"}
                       :aws-user-id "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"}

         :identity "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
         :credential "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
         :jclouds.regions "us-west-2"
         }
})
```